# Ошибка запуска python скрипта

Tags: python

После запуска кода появляется:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file teest.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263 for details
```

```py
what = input("Что делаем (+,-)?: ")
    
a = ("Введите первое число:")
b = ("Введите второе число")

if what == "+"
    c = a + b
    print("Результат:" + с) 
elif what == "-"
    c == a - b 
    print("Результат:" + с)
else:
    print( "выбрана неверная операция")
```

Comment: В том, что ты не объяснил свою проблему.

Comment: После запуска кода появляется : SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file teest.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Answer (score 2):

у вас 3 ошибки:

ошибка 1:

```
a = ("Введите первое число:")
b = ("Введите второе число")
```

вы функцию `input` забыли

ошибка 2:

даже если бы вы не забыли функцию `input`, то забыли бы перевод в числа (например, целые),

т.е. код должен быть таким:

```
a = int(input("Введите первое число:"))
b = int(input("Введите второе число"))
```

ошибка 3:

```
print("Результат:" + с)
```

вы складываете строку и число, что нельзя делать, надо делать так:

```
print("Результат:", с)
print(f"Результат: {c}")
```

Comment: еще одну ошибочку нашел

Comment: в `elif` место сравнения надо поставит присвоение

Comment: кстати да, не заметил сразу!

Comment: после `if` и `elif` нет двоеточий

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, у вас вторая версия питона.
Во второй версии чтобы работать с кириллическими символами, нужно указать кодировку.

Для этого самой первой строкой поставьте вот это:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Либо просто используйте третью версию питона, в нём кириллические символы можно использовать без дополнительных ухищрений.

Ну и в любом случае нужно исправить ошибки, на которые вам указали в соседнем ответе.

Comment: Если вторая, то там `print` без скобок должен быть, а тут будет ругаться. Хотя кто его знает.

Comment: @CrazyElf, нет во второй скобки можно с принтом использовать. Вы же можете любое выражение заключить в скобки, и от этого его смысл не поменяется. Ну и потом до принта же исполнение кода даже не доходит, оно раньше падает.

Comment: Я думал это только с `import __future__` работает, ну да ладно