# в чём моя ошибка?

Tags: python

```
what = input("Что делаем (+,-)?: ")

a = float( input("Введите первое число:") )
b = float( input("Введите второе число") )
if what == "+":
    c = a + b
    print("Результат:" + str (c))   
elif what == "-":
    c == a - b 
    print("Результат:" + str (c))
else:
    print( "выбрана неверная операция")
```

После воспроизведения кода появляется : SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file teest.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: Подозреваю, что дело в том, что у вас кодировка UTF8 BOM. Хотя это не должно мешать. Попробуйте пере сохранить в кодировке UTF8 без BOM

Comment: Скорее всего у вас интерпретатор python 2, а программа написана для python 3

Comment: Какая операционка и в какой кодировке файл?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка запуска python скрипта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211389/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-python-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

Влад, по этому вопросу вам уже отвечал и дополнительно @Danis добавлял найденные ошибки:

[Ошибка запуска python скрипта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211389/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-python-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0/1211397#1211397)

Ваша ошибка в текущем коде:

```
c == a - b
```

Через `==` вы выполняете сравнение, а не присваивание

Вы вообще читаете, что вам среда за ошибки выдает

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "test2.py", line 9, in 
> c == a - b NameError: name 'c' is not defined

P.S.

и на дворе 2020 год, используйте f-строки, вам их специально для этого дали:

вместо

```
print("Результат:" + str (c))
```

лучше

```
print(f"Результат: {c}")
```